# How to add textfield in scrollview in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am making an app in which i am selecting photos from gallery and I want that on every picture or video one textfield will appear so that if i want to describe about that pic or video.

here is the code of display the photos but not showing the textfield on above the every pic in scrollview.

```
-(void)launchController
{
    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc]initImagePicker];

    elcPicker.maximumImagesCount = 100;
    elcPicker.returnsOriginalImage = YES;
    elcPicker.returnsImage = YES;
    elcPicker.onOrder = YES;
    elcPicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeImage,(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
    elcPicker.imagePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
-(void)launchSpecialController
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
    self.specialLibrary = library;
    NSMutableArray *groups = [NSMutableArray array];
    [_specialLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group , BOOL *stop){
        if(group){
            [groups addObject:group];

        }else{
        [self displayPickerForGroup:[groups objectAtIndex:0]];
        }


    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        chosenImages = nil;
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Album Error: %@ - %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

        NSLog(@"A problem occured %@", [error description]);
        // an error here mean
    }];

}
- (void)displayPickerForGroup:(ALAssetsGroup *)group
{
    ELCAssetTablePicker *tablePicker = [[ELCAssetTablePicker alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tablePicker.singleSelection = YES;
    tablePicker.immediateReturn = YES;

    ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tablePicker];
    elcPicker.maximumImagesCount = 1;
    elcPicker.imagePickerDelegate = self;
    elcPicker.returnsOriginalImage = YES; //Only return the fullScreenImage, not the fullResolutionImage
    elcPicker.returnsImage = YES; //Return UIimage if YES. If NO, only return asset location information
    elcPicker.onOrder = NO; //For single image selection, do not display and return order of selected images
    tablePicker.parent = elcPicker;


    tablePicker.assetGroup = group;
    [tablePicker.assetGroup setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allAssets]];

    [self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    return YES;

}else{
    return  toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;

}


}
#pragma mark ELCImageControllerDelegate Methods
-(void)elcImagePickerController:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSArray *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    imageScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150, self.view.frame.size.width, 450)];
    [self.view addSubview:imageScroll];
    UITextField  *textfield1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 40)];
    textfield1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    NSMutableArray *textfieldArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];
    [textfieldArray addObject:textfield1];
    textfield1.text= @"hello";
    [imageScroll addSubview:textfield1];
    for(UIView *v in [imageScroll subviews]){
        [v removeFromSuperview];


    }
    CGRect workingFrame = imageScroll.frame;
    workingFrame.origin.x = 0;

    NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in info) {
        if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypePhoto){
            if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]){
                UIImage* image=[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
                [images addObject:image];

                UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                imageview.frame = workingFrame;

                [imageScroll addSubview:imageview];

                workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = %@", dict);
            }
        } else if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypeVideo){
            if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]){
                UIImage* image=[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

                [images addObject:image];

                UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                imageview.frame = workingFrame;

               [imageScroll addSubview:imageview];
                ;

                workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.origin.x + workingFrame.size.width;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = %@", dict);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uknown asset type");
        }
    }

    chosenImages = images;

    [imageScroll setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [imageScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
}

- (void)elcImagePickerControllerDidCancel:(ELCImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];



}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //chosenImages = [[NSArray alloc]init];


    [super viewDidLoad];



    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

//    textfield1 = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 100, 40)];
//    textfield1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
//    textfieldArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[info count]];
//    [textfieldArray addObject:textfield1];
//    textfield1.text= @"hello";
//    [imageScroll addSubview:textfield1];


    UIButton *uploadimage = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 55, 55)];
    uploadimage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [uploadimage setTitle:@"multiple images" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [uploadimage addTarget:self action:@selector(launchSpecialController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:uploadimage];


    UIButton *singleimage = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 30, 55, 55)];
    singleimage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [singleimage setTitle:@"uploadimage" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [singleimage addTarget:self action:@selector(launchController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:singleimage];


        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
```

Comment: Is there a particular issue that you're having problems with?

Comment: I have asked here what i want and that is the issue.......

Comment: Let me rephrase, are you having trouble creating the `UITextField`? or adding it to scrollView?

Comment: Textfield is not showing on the scrollview even after writing the code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSMutableArray` store `UITextField` value in it and call it with image array with function on the same button.

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutablearray....];
        for (UIView *subV in self.view.subviews){
             if([subV isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
                //store it in a NSDictionary, so later can still know which 
                //textField your text belongs,
                 NSDictionary *tempDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectAndKey:subV.txt 
                                   ,subV.tag,/*or subVw.placeholder*/,nil];
                [arr addObject:tempDic];

           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your code lines. The problem should be there.

Why are you doing below things?

```
[imageScroll addSubview:textfield1];
for(UIView *v in [imageScroll subviews]){
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

In first line you are adding textfield to your scrollview and then you are using for loop to remove all subviews. It will remove your textfield from scrollview as well. You should not do this if you want to show textfield to user.

Please try by commenting the for loop. Hope it will work for you.

//Edit begins over here.

I think you should use UICollectionView instead of UIScrollView. In each and every cells of collectionview, you can show image and textfileds. It will be easy for you and also it will look better.

Thanks